# which of these structure is better?

Tags: python, performance

I'm working on a project in python and i have thought in two ways to write the same code but i want to know which structure is better in performance, semantically and Best Practices.

> version 1

```
if x == 1:
    try:
        order = cliente.order_market_buy(
                symbol = moeda,
                quoteOrderQty=quantidade)
        print(f'buy {order}')

    except Exception as erro:
        print(erro.status_code)
        print(erro.response)
        print(erro.code)
        print(erro.message)
        print(erro.request)
        if erro.code == -2010:
            print('no money')


elif x == -1:
    try:
        order = cliente.order_market_sell(
                symbol = moeda,
                quantity=quantidade)
        print(f'sell {order}')

    except Exception as erro:
        print(erro.status_code)
        print(erro.response)
        print(erro.code)
        print(erro.message)
        print(erro.request)
        if erro.code == -2010:
            print('no crypto')
```

> version 2

```
try:
    if x == 1:
        order = cliente.order_market_buy(
                symbol = moeda,
                quoteOrderQty=quantidade)
        print(f'buy {order}')

    elif x == -1:
        order = cliente.order_market_sell(
                symbol = moeda,
                quantity=quantidade)
        print(f'sell {order}')


except Exception as erro:
        print(erro.status_code)
        print(erro.response)
        print(erro.code)
        print(erro.message)
        print(erro.request)
        if erro.code == -2010:
            if x == 1:
                print('no money')
            elif x == -1:
                print('no crypto')
```

both codes do the same thing, but, the first is easiest to debug, and the second is smaller and cleaner.
Both take the same time to run.

is there another better way to write this?

Comment: #2 is better all around IMO -- why do you think the first is easier to debug?

Comment: The 2nd version is much better because if you need to change the way in which you handle exceptions, then you only need to do it in one place

Comment: I have a slight preference for (1).   In (2), the if/else logic for x appears twice, at different points in the code; I'd rather the logical flow is more localized.

Comment: Version 3, where you use a dict like `{1: cliente.order_market_buy, -1: cliente.order_market_sell}`.

Comment: @Samwise IMO the first is easier because the code only passes through one conditional structure block, the "if x == 1" or "if x == -1".
in the second, the code goes through one of the conditional structure inside the "try" and then through another structure inside the "except"

Comment: ah, I see.  I'll put together an answer with a suggestion for how I'd get rid of that `if` while still having one exception block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having one exception block is preferable IMO if it's doing roughly the same thing in all cases.  Here's how you could avoid having to repeat the `if x` check:

```
try:
    if x == 1:
        currency = "money"
        order = cliente.order_market_buy(
            symbol=moeda,
            quoteOrderQty=quantidade
        )
        print(f'buy {order}')
    elif x == -1:
        currency = "crypto"
        order = cliente.order_market_sell(
            symbol=moeda,
            quantity=quantidade
        )
        print(f'sell {order}')
except Exception as erro:
        print(erro.status_code)
        print(erro.response)
        print(erro.code)
        print(erro.message)
        print(erro.request)
        print(f'no {currency}')
```